# How to resize iframe with real size

Tags: html, iframe

I've visited lots of posts but none of them gived me an answer that works.
I want to resize an iframe to the parent, for example a div.
The iframe tag resizes dynamically the width, but not the height.
How can I dynamically resize both?
If I write: `<iframe src="http..." width="100%" height="400"></iframe>` it always is 400 px of height.
But if I put a % there too it doesn't resize properly.

And if I want to have the iframe width and height of the page it is referencing in src, how can I do it?

Comment: As far as I know you can target it in your css with 'iframe; tag, and then you can set width:100%, height:100%, resize:both, overflow:auto

Comment: I have:
<iframe frameborder="0" width=100% height=100% resize=both overflow=auto  scrollable="no" src="/estadisticaschampionship2.php"></iframe>
How can I prove what you said me?